# How to show UIAlertView for local notification instead of the label-notification which appear at top of the screen in ios7 ?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

because I think beyond iOS5 they remove `UIAlertView` instead of one label appear at the top of screen which I don't want,I am using this code but it doesn't trigger alertview, i need old look of localnotification.

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
localNotification.alertBody = self.itemText.text;
localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the item";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

please Help, Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Users need to change the notification option in Settings app for it.

Comment: can we do it programmatically?

Comment: Sorry you can't, believe me I tried..., although what i ended up doing is having a first page setup and subtly put it in to change in settings for best experience. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notification alert style cannot be changed in our application programmatically. This alert styles shown based on the user wish. If you see in iPhone `settings-> notification center`, you may see all the applications registered for notifications. The user can change the alert style for each application based on their wish. This is not in our hand.

Answer (score 1):

This is not up to the control of the app or the developer (using public API). The user can decide if and how to receive notifications from your app. You may suggest you your user on first launch/tutorial/help that for best experience, you may want to enable alerts instead of banners and perhaps display visual cues on how to do it.